# Is there a way to get historical sale details (specifically geographical areas) on a book?

Tags: book, sales

I ask for legal reasons concerning trademarks, where it's necessary to know where books were sold and when.

Comment: Welcome to writing.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn how things work around here. It's usually a good idea to include the question in the body of your post as well as the title. Thanks for participating and happy writing!

Comment: Wouldn't the publisher have this information?

Answer (score 2):

As Cyn mentioned the publisher may have this information if they're still in business.

Depending on the country the book was published in and how they maintain archives for written works, you may be able to track down information by the Books ISBN or other copyright information.

My suggestion would be to start with the copyright information at the front of the book as it will likely be the most helpful for your search.

Hope this helps :)